# echoing on a div class

Tags: php, syntax, echo

I am trying to change this hardcoded html text into retrieving it from the database. This is the text with the div class.

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2><a href="#">Praesent feugiat felis congue nulla dapibus</a></h2>
    <div class="title-details">
      <a href="#" class="time">May 23, 2012</a>
      <a href="#" class="comments">6</a>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae nibh risus. Morbi dapibus lectus at erat viverra malesuada. Phasellus congue nulla. <a href="#" class="more-link">Read more <b>+</b></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I am trying to retrieve from database, however I am encountering with errors..

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newstable", $connection);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
  echo"<h2>"; echo"<a>"; echo $row['Header']; echo"</h2>";echo"</a>"; 
  echo"<a href="#" class="time">" echo $row['Date'] ;  echo"</a>
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $row['Text'] ;
}   

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not telling us what errors you get, that's what your doing wrong ;-)

Comment: 1. You got some serious style guide issues no offense. 2. Try to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) please. 3. We need the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
  echo"<h2>"; echo"<a>"; echo $row['Header']; echo"</h2>";echo"</a>"; 
  echo"<a href='#' class='time'>"; echo $row['Date'] ;  echo"</a>";
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $row['Text'] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your double quotes within double quoted strings or use single quotes like this:

```
echo"<a href=\"#\" class=\"time\">";
```

Also, you need a semicolon after this echo(once you fix the quotes problem): `echo"<a href="#" class="time">"`

Answer (score 0):

A) Stop using, reading books and accepting instructions that show you how to use mysql_ functions. They are deprecated, and going away.

B) You have 0 error checking. Which means you will be encountering errors until you have an encounter with error checking.

Try this and see what you get: (sadly, I'm helping you with mysql_.....)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newstable", $connection);

// DETERMINE IF YOU HAVE ERRORS
if (!$result ) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

// Since you got here, then $result is usable
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Process your data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is most likely coming from this line:

```
echo "<a href="#" class="time">" echo $row['Date'] ;  echo"</a>
```

If you look closely, you'll notice that you're using double quotes around the HTML attributes and also using double quotes to denote the PHP string.  Switch one of those to single quotes, and you should take care of that error.

What concerns me more, though, is that you are using the [deprecated mysql extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).  Look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) for performing your database operations, as it will help you develop more quickly and [keep your database *much* more secure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Also, instead of echoing every single tag, you can concatenate strings together to help keep your code more readable:

```
echo "<h2>"; echo"<a>"; echo $row['Header']; echo"</h2>";echo"</a>";
```

vs:

```
echo "<h2><a>" . $row['Header'] . "</h2></a>";
```